# Making a decorator with arguments in a flat manner

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know you must've been already tired of Python decorators, but this one seems new! There is a common practice of making [decorators with arguments](//stackoverflow.com/q/739654).
But [Flat is better than nested](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), so let's flatten it up:

```
def decorator_with_args(arg):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('decorated with arg: {}'.format(arg))
        return wrapper.func(*args, **kwargs)

    def wrapper_creator(decorable):
        wrapper.func = decorable
        return functools.wraps(decorable)(wrapper)

    return wrapper_creator
```

Wrapped `func` is passed as an attribute, `arg` - via closure. They don't get overwritten with multiple *consequent* calls to `decorator_with_args`.

But not *chained* ones - `functools.wraps` will update `wrapper`'s `__dict__`, overwriting its `func` attribute like this:

```
@decorator_with_args('This decorator will be applied')
@decorator_with_args('Others will not')
def gotcha():
    pass
```

So, attributes are not a good place to store our `func`. But closure seems to be. Let's use it:

```
def decorator_with_args(arg):
    func = None

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('decorated with arg: {}'.format(arg))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    def wrapper_creator(decorable):
        nonlocal func
        func = decorable
        return functools.wraps(decorable)(wrapper)

    return wrapper_creator
```

Now it looks good to me! Does it to you? Is it pythonic, idiomatic, correct and nicely performing?

And a real example of making something useful (this is a part to be reviewed):

```
import functools
import logging
import logging.config


def temp_loglevel(level):
    """
    A decorator for setting temporary loglevel for the scope of
    the wrapped function, then reverting it back on wrapper exit

    Arguments:
        level: new logging level to set
    """
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    func = None

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        old_level = logger.level
        logger.setLevel(level)
        rv = func(*args, **kwargs)
        logger.setLevel(old_level)
        return rv

    def wrapper_maker(decorable):
        nonlocal func
        func = decorable
        logger.warn(
            "temp_loglevel used, don't forget to "
            "remove it when debugging is done"
        )

        return functools.wraps(decorable)(wrapper)

    return wrapper_maker


logging.config.dictConfig(dict(
    version = 1,
    disable_existing_loggers = False,
    formatters = {
        'default': {
            'format': '%(asctime)-15s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s'
        }
    },
    handlers = {
        'std': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'default'
        }
    },
    root = {
        'handlers': ['std'],
        'propagate': False,
        'level': 'INFO'
    }
))


@temp_loglevel(logging.DEBUG)
def print_debug():
    logging.getLogger().debug('This should be visible')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_debug()
```

I would be glad if you put some critique of my code styling as well!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I don't understand what code we're reviewing, though. This decorator and it's argument doesn't seem to accomplish anything. It seems that you are asking for opinions about the general practice of splitting up arguments into multiple decorators, in which case I am voting to close this question as hypothetical.

Comment: @200_success Oh, sorry. It is a bit stripped off example to focus the attention on one aspect of the implementation - the decorator itself (not the wrapper), and to facilitate things for those willing to run it (to test their own ideas or use cases). I could add my real production code if needed. Should I?

Comment: @ogurets Yes, because unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709).

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Done!

Answer (score 1):

I've found a couple bugs - lack of exception support and it doesn't work with generators. Well, it does in a way, but not the way someone would *expect* it to.

To fix aforementioned issues, decorator have been changed into this (nevermind Python 2.7 compatibility modifications):

```
def temp_loglevel(level):
    """
    Decorator to set temporary loglevel for the scope of this function
    (then revert it back on wrapper exit)

    Arguments:
        level: new logging level to set
    """
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    p_closure = dict(func=None)

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        old_level = logger.level
        logger.setLevel(level)
        try:
            rv = p_closure['func'](*args, **kwargs)
            if isinstance(rv, types.GeneratorType):
                def wrapper_gen():
                    # wrapper's finally block overrides initial setLevel after
                    # returning a generator object
                    logger.setLevel(level)
                    try:
                        for x in rv:
                            yield x
                    finally:
                        logger.setLevel(old_level)

                return wrapper_gen()
            else:
                return rv
        finally:
            logger.setLevel(old_level)

    def wrapper_maker(decorable):
        p_closure['func'] = decorable
        logger.warn(
            "temp_loglevel used, don't forget to "
            "remove it when debugging is done"
        )

        return functools.wraps(decorable)(wrapper)

    return wrapper_maker
```

P.S. After thinking about how ugly would a flat version of `wrapper_gen` be, I've made a mental note to myself: "flat is better than nested", but if you **absolutely need** to make something nested, do it FFS!